# Django: ImportError: cannot import name 'User'

Tags: python, django, django-models, model, django-users

I'm new to django and I'm facing some difficulties in creating a user from the AbstractBaseUser model. Now I'm starting wondering if my user model is not being build in the right way. This is my User model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    '''
    Custom user class.
    '''
    username = models.CharField('username', max_length=10, unique=True, db_index=True)
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)
    joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and user is only referenced in this other model

```
from django.db import models
from user_profile import User

class Tweet(models.Model):
    '''
    Tweet model
    '''
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

then when I try to migrate my new model into db

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/myuser/django-book/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/myuser/django-book/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/myuser/django-book/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/myuser/django-book/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/myuser/django-book/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/myuser/django-book/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/myuser/django-book/mytweets/tweets/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from user_profile import User
ImportError: cannot import name 'User'
```

I'm using django 1.10.1 on ubuntu 16.04 with python3.5 and mysql as database.

Comment: What's your directory structure? Are the two modules in different directories?

Comment: Did you try renaming 'User' model into something as 'UserProfile'. Try and use unique usernames for User models as `django.contrib.auth.models` also contains a model named as `User`.

Comment: actually they were on different applications... But @Zulfugar 's answer solved my problem. It was a newbie mistake

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't import from right package.

Use:

```
from user_profile.models import User
```

Comment: when did it became mandatory to specify models after the application name? the tutorial that I'm following does not search dor the models in the submodule "models"

Comment: @WisdomPill your class is probably in models.py file and file is in application folder. That's why you should import from models.

Comment: I don't know why is this accepted. I get error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'user_profile'
`

Comment: @Tessaracter you probably need a `__init__.py` file in your user_profile folder

Comment: Big oof! I needed the ".models" portion of it... such a simple mistake!

Answer (score 8):

I solved this by importing

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Comment: You important the default User model, the question is about important his custom user model

Comment: This works for importing User, but why do they not state "django.contrib.auth.models" in the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You can change it to

`user = models.ForeignKey('<usermodel>.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by importing

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
```

Check the right spell of the package

Answer (score 0):

I had a makemigrations problem while creating a new custom User model mid project.

My solution to this problem was to import CustomNameUser from users.models app.

Might help those with similar questions to yours but with a similar context.

CustomNameUser being the class name of the custom User model that you extended AbstractUser or AbstractBaseUser

Sample code:
users/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'
```

app/models.py

```
...
from users.models import CustomUser
...

class ClassName():
  ...
  user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
  ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you import User and not user

'' `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63065031/2227743).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).